# C++ Program calculate carpet cost of rooms

Tags: c++, function, cout

Currently I am in a C++ class and were are learning about functions. Our assignment was to create a program to calculate the total cost including price per sq foot, labor, and tax of each room given by the user's input for the count. Here is my program, which I can't get to compile and I do not know why. Thanks for anyone who helps me I greatly appreciate it.

For example, the input:
2
2 2 2
2 2 2

Should give the output:
2 2 22.4

but it is printing this instead:

2 2 9.87

I have no clue what is wrong.. I looked at all my formulas and they look correct.  A room with dimensions of 2*2, cost per sq foot of 2, should give a total cost of 11.2, I'm am so confused.  Maybe I set the functions up incorrectly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void getdata (int&, int&, float&);
float InstalledPrice (int , int, float );
float totalprice (float);
void printdata (int , int, float);


int length, width, count, x;
float installation, costpersqfoot, price;

int main()
{



    cout << "Enter the amount of rooms.\n";
    cin >> x;

    for(count = x; count != 0; count --)
    {
        getdata (length, width, costpersqfoot);
        InstalledPrice (length, width, costpersqfoot);
        totalprice (installation);
        if (count ==1)
        {
            printdata (length, width, price);
        }   

    }

}

void getdata(int & length, int & width, float & costpersqft)
{
    cin >> length >> width >> costpersqft;
}

float InstalledPrice (int a, int b, float c)
{
    installation = 0;
    const float LABOR_COST = 0.35;
    float sqfoot;
    sqfoot = length * width;
    installation = (costpersqfoot * sqfoot) + (LABOR_COST * sqfoot) + installation;
}

float totalprice(float installation)
{
    const float TAX_RATE = 0.05;
    price = (installation * TAX_RATE) + installation;
}

void printdata(int length, int width, float price)
{
    cout << length << " " << width << " " << price << endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. "I can't get to compile": It doesn't sound like that's what you mean. You wouldn't be able to run the program if it didn't compile. Are you able to set breakpoints and step through the code to see where the problem is occurring?

Comment: You should defintely have a look at my answer to your previous question. You've moved to global variables, which is the wrong thing to so. You're missing a fundamental concept which is how to make a function return a value.

Comment: I agree with @john... this is C++, not Excel.  You need to understand how functions return values.

Answer (score 0):

In function

```
float InstalledPrice (int a, int b, float c)
```

you are resetting value of installation every time you execute the function.

```
installation = 0;
```

Try removing that line and insert it before the for loop in main function.

```
installation = 0;
for(count = x; count != 0; count --)
```

With the constants in your code, It would print `19.74`
((4 * 2) + (4 * 0.35) = 9.4 for each room, 18.8 for two rooms. With tax, (18.8 * 1.05) = 19.74)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of things going on here, the most important of which is to address returning values from functions as @john said. In terms of just your mathematics though, consider 1 room of 2ft x 2ft with a cost of 2 per sqft - your installation price comes out to be `installation = (2 * 4) + (.35 * 4) + 0`, which is 9.4. Later in your program, you add in the tax, 
`price = 9.4 * .05 + 9.4`, which gives you 9.87. Not sure where the 11.2 you mention is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you fall off the end of a function returning something else than `void` the program has undefined behavior, i.e., it can do whatever it wants. Producing other output than those expected is about the mildest form it can take.

Here are the changes to the code you should:

1. Any function declared to return a value shall have a `return` statement (`main()` is an exception and it diesn't absolutely require a `return` although it returns `int` but it is good style to still use `return 0;`).
2. You should verify that all inputs are actually successful, e.g., using something like:

   ```
   if (std::cin >> length >> width >> costpersquarefeet) {
       // process the entered data
   }
   else {
       std::cerr << "ERROR: failed to read inoyt!\n";
   }
   ```

   I would probably use a more detailed chrck and also tell the user what input I'm expecting.
3. Do **not** use global variables! There extremely few cases where they are necessary and even the you are best off to use a different approach! (i.e. define them as `static` variable inside a function and access them somehow; you can learn about global variables when you necessary which likely to be in quite some future).

Answer (score 0):

```
                            #include <iostream>
                            #include <time.h>
                            #include <stdlib.h>

                            // This program is writen by KHUMBELO DIFFERENCE MUTHAVHINE from Ha- Vhangani . Khumbelo is a programmer 

                            using namespace std;
                            // call function calculateCarpetSize
                               void CalculateCarpetSize (int  &length, int &width, int &carpetSize)
                               {

                                      carpetSize = length * width;

                               }


                            // call function calculateCarpetCost
                            void CalculateCarpetCost (int &carpetSize , float &sellingPrice , float &carpetCost  )
                            {

                                float tax = 0.14;
                                carpetCost = carpetSize * sellingPrice * tax;

                            }


                            // call function calculateLabourCost
                            CalculateLabourCost(int &carpetSize , int &labour, float &labourCost)
                            {

                                labourCost = carpetSize * labour;
                             }

                              bool qualifyForDiscount(int &customerNo){


                                 if (customerNo <=9999)
                                    {
                                      void computeDiscount (float &carpetCost );
                                    return true ;
                                    }
                                    else{return false;
                                    }

                                }

                                       // call function computeDiscount
                                    void computeDiscount (float &carpetCost, float &discountPercentage )
                                       {

                                        cout << "Enter the percetage discout: "<< endl;
                                        cin >> discountPercentage ;
                                        carpetCost = carpetCost * discountPercentage;

                                       }


                                  // call function printCustomerStatement
                              void printCustomerStatement( )
                                  {
                                  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
                                  cout << endl;
                                  cout << "CROSWELL CARPET STORE" << endl;
                                  cout << "STATEMENT" << endl;




                              }
                            int main()
                            {
                              int customerNo;
                              string customerName, customersurname;
                              float roomLength;
                              float roomWidth, discountPercentage;

                              float sellingPrice;
                              float carpetCost;
                              float labourCost;
                              float discount;
                              int carpetSize;
                              int rooLength, roonWidth;
                              int labour = 24;
                              //float labourCost;

                               cout.setf(ios::fixed);
                               cout.precision(2);
                               cout << "\nPlease enter the following information: ";
                               cout << "\n Customer FIRST name: ";
                               cin >> customerName;
                               cout << "\n Customer LAST name: ";
                               cin >> customersurname;
                               cout << "\n Customer number: ";
                               cin >> customerNo;
                               cout << "\n The length of the room: ";
                               cin >> roomLength;
                               cout << "\n The width of the room: ";
                               cin >> roomWidth;
                               cout << "\n The carpet selling price: ";
                               cin >> sellingPrice;
                               // call function calculateCarpetSize
                             CalculateCarpetSize (rooLength, roonWidth, carpetSize);
                               // call function calculateCarpetCost
                             CalculateCarpetCost (carpetSize ,sellingPrice, carpetCost  );
                            // call function calculateLabourCost
                             CalculateLabourCost(carpetSize , labour, labourCost);
                             if (customerNo<= 9999){
                             bool   qualityForDiscout(customerNo);
                             computeDiscount (carpetCost, discountPercentage );
                             }

                              // call function computeDiscount





                                        // call function printCustomerStatement
                                 // printCustomerStatement(customerName, customerNo, carpetCost, labourCost, discount);
                                  printCustomerStatement();

                               cout << "\n Customer name: ";
                               cout << customerName <<  customersurname<<endl;
                               cout << "\n Customer number: ";
                               cout << customerNo <<endl;
                               cout << "\n The length of the room: ";
                               cout << roomLength <<endl;
                               cout << "\n The width of the room: ";
                               cout<< roomWidth <<endl;
                               cout << "\n The carpet selling price: ";
                               cout<< "sellingPrice:" <<  sellingPrice <<endl;

                             return 0;
                            } // end main
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit?